# What's the difference between ɐ and a?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, ipa

I really can't tell the difference between these two. At first I thought that ɐ was something similar to ə, but I'm not sure. I'd appreciate any examples to distinguish these sounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen to expert IPA pronunciations of the difference [here](http://www.phonetics.ucla.edu/course/chapter1/wells/wells.html). "Examples" would come from a specific language. As you can see from the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_central_unrounded_vowel) on the vowel, it is widely transcribed as [ə], but maybe [a]. It does not apparently contrast with [ə] in one language, but may be found in certain dialects instead of [ə]. It may also be conflated with [ɜ]. It is most useful to compare the performance pronunciations of the above-linked experts, since IPA does not specify particular formant values or lexical items in specific languages as representing the value of a given symbol.

If you go to [Forvo](https://forvo.com/languages/de/), you can get over a half million pronunciations of German words. There is a difference between *er* and *e* at the end of the word, where final *er* may be [ɐ]. I don't know of a way to efficiently assemble all of the relevant words, but this is a resource for potentially hearing examples (I'd generally suggest listening to anything with final *r*). It might be best to pick a [single speaker](https://forvo.com/user/ReinerSelbstschuss/pronounced-words/) and listen to their pronunciations. Sometimes [speakers differ](https://forvo.com/word/kiffer/), and you can pick a speaker who has the pronunciation of interest like the first one, and see what [similar words](https://forvo.com/user/DjangoFett/) there are. [Some words](https://forvo.com/search/br%C3%BCder/) are attested with multiple recordings.

Comment: What does this part mean: "It does not apparently contrast with [ə] in one language"? My understanding was that some varieties of German do have a contrast between a phone commonly transcribed [ə] and another phone commonly transcribed [ɐ], e.g. in "eine" [ˈaɪnə] vs. "einer" [ˈaɪnɐ]...

Comment: ...although the phonetic details and phonological analysis are not so obvious (German [ə] is typically considered to be an allophone of /ɛ/ in unstressed syllables, and I have heard that in some accents of German, the sound typically transcribed [ə] is in fact closer in quality to [ɛ]; furthermore, I have heard that some native German speakers find that [ɐ] doesn't really sound distinct from German short "a", although this could be because they actually use a not-fully-open quality for "short a")

Comment: I don't know about that variety of German. If these are indeed phonologically distinct as vowel quality, then it would mean that I have to invoke the "apparently" escape, and say "except in German" if it can be established. I'm really not clear what the status of those r's are.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was a fairly well-known variety since I see that style of transcription a lot in materials for learners. E.g. this word-reference thread: [Pronunciation: -er = -ɐ?](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pronunciation-er-ɐ.2530017) and this book *[German Phonetics and Phonology: Theory and Practice](https://books.google.com/books?id=8lGODQAAQBAJ&pg=PA325&lpg=PA325&dq=German+ɐ&source=bl&ots=S-AbkX4OQ-&sig=N0bq8jaNR4H2Z2s3s6zE0FM1og4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJkKiygNvYAhWRw4MKHYwOADkQ6AEIYTAI#v=onepage&q=ɐ&f=false)* (By Mary Grantham O'Brien, Sarah M. B. Fagan).

Comment: I forgot to mention, [ɐ] is also (often, at least) not considered a phoneme of German: it can be analyzed as /əʁ/ or /ɛʁ/. And actually, what I said earlier about [ə] being analyzed as an allophone of /ɛ/ doesn't actually seem to be done by all phonological analyses, although I don't know why not: http://users.monash.edu.au/~ewilkins/textbook/CHAP12.PDF

Comment: [Wikipedia "Standard German phonology"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German_phonology#Monophthongs) says  Wiese (1996:16–17) has some discussion of the phonological analysis of these vowels

Comment: "It does not apparently contrast with [ə] in one language, but may be found in certain dialects instead of [ə]." <-- Does *one language* there mean *any* language? Because in British English we have minimal pairs such as *an orthodoxy* and *unorthodoxy*, which are distinct for many speakers.

Comment: To be more precise, the claim is about a single grammar (which is a speaker thing). Your example could be relevant, except for the question of whether "juncture" differences can be disregarded in establishing contrast. I'm not a fan of the "minimal pair" approach to contrast, but if we go that way, I think the differences do have to be minimal. Incidentally, I have no idea which vowel is supposed to be which in that pair.